# Getting image id on click and set it as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a few images in a list:

```
    <div id="accordion">

                <h3><a href="#">Screen Category:</a></h3>

            <div>
                <ul class="filters">
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryAdvertising" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/info.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryInformation" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryACA" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/entertainment.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryEntertainment" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryInfluencing" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryICE" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryCommunication" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" id="categoryParticipation" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                <h3><a href="#">Screen Type:</a></h3>

            <div>
                <ul class="filters">
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/communicate.png" title="" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/filters/new/info.png" title="" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the image id on clicking the image and then fadingitout. I also have a boolean variable the same as the image id which I want to set to true if it is false.

If the variable same as the image id is already true then I want to set it to false and fade the image out.

Unfortunatly my click function issint working at all.

this is what I have so far:

```
$("img.filters").click(function () {
alert("clicked");
    var id = ($(this).attr('id'));
    $('#' + id).fadeTo("slow", 1.00);
});
```

since it is not working at all I am guessing I did something wrong with the element.

Thanx in advance for you help!

Comment: Can you give us a link to an example.  All the scripts that you have so far said don't work _will_ fade out the image when clicked.  I know that's not exactly what you want, but let's deal with the click event first and then take it from there.

Comment: This should help then: http://jsfiddle.net/tDYcX/7/

Comment: Is this more like what you're looking for?    http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/HueDV/

The main problem with all the examples is that none of them explained you need to run the code on document ready.  I added an extra little something to make the fade toggle, but nothing more.

Comment: for the fading yes. But I also need to set the variabels with the same name as the image IDs to true or false.

Comment: This will be frowned upon, as the use of eval is not popular.  http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/kYz8k/3/  There are better ways to do what you are asking.  For one, you could simply get the state of the image if you want a true/false value, rather than storing it as a local variable but there's lots of ways to get a true/false value from what you're doing.

Comment: I see, It seems to work indeed. Thanx. I woudnt be able come up with it or anything better :p

Comment: No problem.  I'll post the jsfiddle link as an answer so it's more obvious for people who get here by searching for the same thing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This toggles the opacity of the images when clicked...

```
$(function() {
    var bools = {};
    $(".filters img").click(function () {
        if (bools[this.id]) {
            opacity = 0.5;
            bools[this.id] = false;
        } else {
            opacity = 1;
            bools[this.id] = true;
        }
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", opacity);
    });
});
```

It keeps a local var that contains the state of all the images so it knows whether to show or hide them, without having to parse the DOM state every time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of capturing img id you can simply use `this`:

Using the `on` method allows you to add elements after the event is bound.

```
$(document).on("click", ".filters img", function() { 
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

About your variables is there any change you can same them in an object?

```
var vars = {
    categoryAdvertising: false,
    categoryInformation: false
};
```

then you can toggle them using: (in your click event)

```
vars[this.id] = !vars[this.id];
```

`this` refers to the clicked DOM element. So you can simple capture the id using `this.id`

See : http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-id-vs-this-id

**NOTE:**

Se how nice the `!` operator works.

```
!true is false
!false is true
```

If you bind the `click` event on the `li` tag as i will do later on. You can capture the id using:

```
$(this).children("img")[0].id
```

or

```
$(this).children("img").attr("id");
```

---

**You just want to fade toggle the image?** You can use [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".filters img", function() { 
   alert("clicked");
   $(this).fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

the problem here is when the image is hidden it's gets `display:none;` and therefore can't be clicked again: http://jsfiddle.net/jJDvc/1/

The fix can be to bind the click event on it's parent (the `li` element): http://jsfiddle.net/jJDvc/2/

```
$(document).on("click", ".filters li", function() {
   $(this).children("img").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

And then have some style for the parent as well.

```
li {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

---

Hopes this answers some of your many questions.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work as the click is not triggered somehow. I am using id beacause I want to set the variable which has same name as the id to true or false.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is the following: I have several images which will be used as a checbox like filter for the markers on my google maps. When an image is clicked I want it to fade to full opacity and turn the variable I have true for that image(variable has the same name as the ID) Then if the image is clicked again it should fadeout and set the variabele to false. I have a demo at JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDYcX/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, should be

```
$(".filters img").click(function () { 
alert("clicked"); 
    var id = ($(this).attr('id')); 
    $('#' + id).fadeTo("slow", 1.00); 
});
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work as the click is not triggered somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be:

```
$(".filters img").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
    var id = ($(this).attr('id'));
    $('#' + id).fadeTo("slow", 1.00);
});
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work as the click is not triggered somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".filters img").live('click',function () {
  alert("clicked");
  $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.00);
  return false;
});
```

Or create a class for the images that you want to trigger the event, and select them by that class. Assuming the new class is ".clicking-images":

```
$(".clicking-images").live('click',function () {
  alert("clicked");
  $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.00);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: thanx the .live seems to work compared to the .click. Whats the difference?

Comment: In short, [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) prepares the function to be handled even if elements are loaded dynamically (after the declaration of the function, which is often the case in AJAX websites)

Comment: I tried replacing .live with .on because .live is depreciated but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery code you have given as **img.filter** which means **img** tag with the class name as **filters**, but in your html there is no img tag with the class name filter, so change your code as shown below

```
$(".filters li img").click(function () {
alert("clicked");
     $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.00);
});
```

Hope this solves your problem